# Send mail to contact using their alias

Tags: c#, interop, outlook, office-interop

I develop an application using Outlook. This application sends mail automatically to users defined in an Excel file.

Problem is, my Excel file contains only the aliases (or the whole email address, it depends).

In the most cases, the use of :

```
Recipient recipient = App.Session.CreateRecipient(item);
recipient.Resolve();

if (!recipient.Resolved)
{
    // ???
}
```

Sometimes, alias are not enough (because autocompletion will suggest more that one address), but I want to use the first address that have this alias / initials, how can I do that?

P.S: My contact list is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it by myself, one solution was to get the ExchangeUser from all address lists. Once this, you can easily retrieve an user by his alias and create a recipient according the address.

Hope it helps.